# how to change vimeo video source to local mp4 video using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, vimeo, video.js, video-player

I'm trying to make a video player which contains vimeo and local video but I'm dont know how  to switch the video source to local video if the vimeo video fails to play.Im using video.js.any help please :)

here is my coding:

HTML

```
<video id="vid1" src="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="360">
```

Javascript:

```
videojs('vid1', { "techOrder": ["vimeo"], "src": "https://vimeo.com/63186969" }).ready(function() {
// You can use the video.js events even though we use the vimeo controls
// As you can see here, we change the background to red when the video is paused and set it back when unpaused
this.on('pause', function() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
});

this.on('play', function() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = '';
});

// You can also change the video when you want
// Here we cue a second video once the first is done
this.one('ended', function() {
  this.src('http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4');
  this.play();
});
```

i make some changes to my js but still unable to change.im new to javascript..please help me :)

Javascript:

```
videojs('vid2', { "techOrder": ["vimeo"], "src": "https://vimeo.com/63186969" }).ready(function() {
    // You can use the video.js events even though we use the vimeo controls
    // As you can see here, we change the background to red when the video is paused and set it back when unpaused
    this.on('pause', function() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    });

    this.on('play', function() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = '';
    });

    // You can also change the video when you want
    // Here we cue a second video once the first is done
    this.one('ended', function() {
        this.src('http://vimeo.com/79380715');
        this.play();
    });   

    myPlayer.src("http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4");
    var myPlayer = videojs('vid2');
    myPlayer.ready(function(){ /*Video is ready*/ });
    myPlayer.error(function(){ /*An error happened*/ });
    mpPlayer.play();
]);
```

Comment: i make some adjustment to my javascript coding but still unable to change the video source..here is my js code:

Answer (score 0):

So there are the 2 events:

```
var myPlayer = videojs('example_video_1');
myPlayer.ready(function(){ /*Video is ready*/ });
myPlayer.error(function(){ /*An error happened*/ });
```

More api info here : https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/api/vjs.Player.md